# Why was type checking not happening on second parameter and only on first parameter?

Tags: c, typechecking

In the below code when I entered 'a' value as 3.4(i.e. float) it is giving me answer garbage value without even allowing me to enter the 'b' value and when I given 'a' value as 3 and 'b' value as 2.3(i.e. float) it is accepted and giving me answer 5 not a garbage.

My question is why type checking was not happening on second parameter ;why only on first parameter?

more clearly if I give 3,3.5 code is working but why cant i give input as 3.5,3 ?

```
int sum(int k,int l)
{
  int s= k+l;
  return s;
}

void main()
{
  int a,b,k;
  printf("enter the numbers");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  scanf("%d",&b);
  k= sum(a,b);
  printf("the value of sum is %d", k);
}
```

PS: I saw this question on quora. I was not happy with the answers provided there. I thought SO is the best place to ask this question.

Comment: Because `scanf()` doesn't work as you think it works. Read its man page. (And be horrified and **stop using scanf.**)

Comment: @user3477950 You mean this ? "The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe how to process the sequence of input characters. If processing of a directive fails, no further input is read, and scanf() returns. A "failure" can be either of the following: input failure, meaning that input characters were unavailable, or matching failure, meaning that the input was inappropriate (see below)."

Comment: `scanf("%d",&b);` , It will stop the input with a period(`.`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type checking is not the issue in your program. Type checking happens at compilation time; the behavior you're seeing occurs at run time. There is an issue with compile-time type checking for `printf`, `scanf`, and similar functions, which I discuss below, but that doesn't apply to your program, which does pass arguments of the correct type to both `scanf` and `printf`. Nevertheless, I'll discuss that issue below (because I wrote about it before I read your question closely enough).

You call `scanf` twice to (attempt to) read two `int` values. The input is `3.4`, which would be valid input for a `float` or `double`. So what does `scanf` do with this?

`scanf` with a `"%d"` format reads input formatted like an optionally signed integer literal, stopping when it sees anything that doesn't match that format. So the first `scanf` reads just the `3` and stops at the `.`. It doesn't consider that the `.` might be a decimal point because you didn't ask it to read a floating-point value. The `.` isn't an error, it's just the end of the input that `scanf("%d", ...)` is looking for.

The second `scanf` attempts to read another `int` value, but now the first character in the input stream is the `.`, which cannot be part of a valid integer literal, so it fails. (Examining the return value of `scanf` would tell you this; it returns the number of items successfully scanned.)

You should *always* check the results returned by input functions and write code to handle failure (even if you handle it just by aborting the program with an error message).

A safer way to read numeric input is to read an entire line at a time using `fgets()`, and then parse the line in memory using `sscanf`. That can have problems too, but it won't leave invalid input characters waiting to be read by later calls (unless you have a very long input line). Read the documentation of `fgets` and `sscanf` for more information -- and again, always check the results they return so you can detect input errors.

---

Both `printf` and `scanf` are *variadic* functions, meaning that they can accept a variable number and types of arguments.

The declaration of `printf`, for example, is:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

This means that the first argument in a call to `printf` is checked against the parameter type, but the zero or more following arguments are not checked at compile time. This gives you tremendous flexibility, but at the cost of compile=time checking. It's almost entirely up to you to ensure that all the following arguments are of the types specified by the format string. If you pass an argument of the wrong type (e.g., `printf("%d\n", 1.5)`), you won't necessarily get an error message; instead, the behavior is undefined.

`scanf` is similar, but with different semantics for the format string (most arguments are pointers rather than values to be printed).

Some compilers (gcc in particular) will do additional checking for you if the format string is a string literal, but this is not required and other compilers might not do this.

---

Incidentally, the code you posted is missing the required

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you're using a book or tutorial that suggests using `void main()`, it was probably written by someone who doesn't know the C language very well. Find a better one.

Comment: First part: Excellent explanation. Thanks.
</br>
Second part: Are you sure that variable number of arguments are not type checked during compile time ? Because if i compile with gcc -Wall, I get warnings for not specifying the correct number and/or type of arguments.
</br>
Third part: Yes.I always use int main(void). As I mentioned in the question I copied the question from quora. So pasted as is.

Comment: @CCoder: As I wrote, type checking for `printf` format strings is not required, but compilers are allowed to print additional warnings about anything they like. gcc does so, but only if the format string is known at compile time. (It's legal, but potentially dangerous, to build a format string at run time.)

Answer (score 1):

When scanf encounters a double for variable 'a' as you noted 3.4. It reads 3 as the integer and stops at the decimal. the .4 will then be read as a double on the next call. It works when the second input is a float because it drops the decimal and is not called again thus ignoring the remaining decimals.
As noted in the comments, read about scanf and make some changes to the code.

Comment: " the .4 will then be read as a double on the next call". Seriously ?

Answer (score -2):

I think you should add "getchar()" after scanf method,when you press enter,the '/n' will give
next parameter.
it's just my point.

```
void main()
{
  int a,b,k;
  printf("enter the numbers");
  scanf("%d",&a);

  getchar();/* the /n is last in stdin*/

  scanf("%d",&b);
  k= sum(a,b);
  printf("the value of sum is %d", k);
}
```

Comment: I do a test.my code can run perfect.I hope it can help you.

Comment: That works when there happens to be one invalid character between the two integers, as in `3.4`. It doesn't help if the input is `3..4`, or if there's no valid input at all. The real problem is failing to check the result returned by `scanf`, and thus failing to detect input errors.

Comment: Oh,my god.It is my fault.Thanks for your advise. Thompson.